# PDO login Error

Tags: php, html, pdo

**ERROR**
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined !

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';
    if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
    {
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $user_password = trim($_POST['password']);
        $password = md5($user_password);
        try{
            $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user1 WHERE username=:username");
            $stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$username));
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            if($row['user_password']==$password){
            echo "ok"; // log in
            $_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['username'];
            }
            else{
                    echo "email or password does not exist."; // wrong details 
                }
            }
             catch(PDOException $e) {
                   echo $e->getMessage();
                 }
           }
        ?>
```

What is the correct code? Please anybody find out the error and give correct formation of code

Answer (score 1):

Your `execute()` statement is wrong. See here,

```
$stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$username));
                         ^
```

It should be,

```
$stmt->execute(array(":username"=>$username));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !.  But user name and password enter after nothing do same page only show why?

Comment: *...user name and password enter after nothing do same page only show*, what do you mean?

Comment: if correct details enter after go to home page or else show error message at wrong details. But nothing show.

Comment: i was trying to http://demos.codingcage.com/ajax-login/ this link for my own table

I have follow this code only. But this one work online in perfect. same code not working for me.

Comment: You're not using `$count` variable *anywhere*. Do this, `if($count){ // username exists, process further }else{ echo "username doesn't exist"; }`

Comment: sorry how put the code in my file i don t know. Because i m in new for PHP.

Comment: @sarathi your code seems to work fine on your url after this update. I was able to login to your site

Comment: @sarathi There are several things wrong in your code. For example, you're using password as it is, no hashing. You're not using `header();` followed by `exit();` to redirect the user to different page. You're not making use of `$count` variable and so on. Please know that if you don't know the basic logic of the system then one error will lead to another and you'll go round and round. Just do a little [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pdo+login+example) to learn about these things..